# Executing multiple procedures in SQL Server without having to redeclare variable

Tags: sql, variables, loops, procedure

I have a series of stored procedures all using the same variable. I would like each stored procedure to execute completely before moving onto the next one. I added a GO statement at the end of each procedure, but I don't want to have to redeclare the variable after each run. Is there a way to loop back to the variable after the GO, then pick up the next proc in the sequence? Below is an example of the code for reference:

```
DECLARE @depType AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @deptype='X'

EXEC [Stored_Procedure1], @deptype
GO

EXEC [Stored_Procedure2], @deptype
GO

EXEC [Stored_Procedure3], @deptype
GO
```

Comment: What makes you think they will run in parallel? they are executed serially

Answer (score 2):

Just leave out `GO` statements:

```
DECLARE @depType AS VARCHAR(20);
SET @deptype='X';

EXEC [Stored_Procedure1], @deptype;

EXEC [Stored_Procedure2], @deptype;

EXEC [Stored_Procedure3], @deptype;
```

They define a batch and variables are only defined within a batch.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, but I actually need the procedures to complete successfully without moving on to the next one. My assumption was that only occurs if you include the GO. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Would doing

`GO TO;
-- Stored_Procedure1
EXEC [Stored_Procedure1], @deptype;`

Help at all?